# Netsuite RESTlet can't set SalesRep

Tags: netsuite

I am creating a Quote (estimate record type) in my Restlet, and assigning the customer to the quote and want to override the default salesrep that would autopopulate based on the customer. So I'm including:

```
record.setFieldValue('salesrep', datain.salesrep);
```

The Quote gets created fine, but the salesrep field still goes back to the default value. Any idea how to override this relationship to the customer record associated with the Quote?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting the `salesrep` field *after* you set the customer, otherwise it will be sourced in again when you select the customer.

Comment: Tried that. Tried submitting record without setting any sales rep, then set the sales rep field and resubmit. Still reverts back to default!